# Directly accessing member variables vs inline accessor functions

Tags: c++

I'm currently developing a game but am curious about a performance comparison.
Should I be declaring my class member variables public and access them directly, or should they be left private and accessed with a simple inline function that returns that variable's value?
At university (in Computer Science - not gamedev) we are always encouraged to use accessor and mutator like functions. However, I've seen some classes from game engines where they directly accessed the member variables.
Is performance comparable here? Which way should I go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a function will be inlined by the compiler anyway, with a high probability of getting exactly the same code.

There's no difference in performance, base your choice on other tradeoffs (encapsulation, invariants protection, ease of use...).